# Ruby on Rails: Using Unless for Validation, JQuery Validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

In my model, I have the following:

```
attr_accessor :address, :located_in_us

validates_length_of :address, :in => 1..50, :message => "Required field, please enter your address."
```

On my form, I have a radio button that asks whether or not they are located in the US.  If they select "Yes" then I want the address field to be required.  When they click "No" I have a show/hide that hides the DIV that contains the address, but the form will never submit because the field, even though it's hidden, it's still required.

I tried the following:

```
validates_length_of :address, :in => 1..50, :message => "Required field, please enter your address.", :unless => :located_in_us == "1"
```

But it doesn't seem to work because the javascript added below the address looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>$(function() { $('[name="myform[address]"]').rules('add', {"maxlength":50,"required":true,"unless":false,"minlength":1,"messages":{"required":"Required field, please enter your address."}});});</script>
```

My question is...how do I make the form so that when the user clicks the "No" radio button (they don't live in the US) that the address field is no longer a required field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `:unless` option for the model validation is supposed to be a `lambda` or a `Proc`:

```rb
validates_length_of :address, :in => 1..50, :message => "Required field, please enter your address.", :unless => lambda { |o| o.located_in_us == "1" }
```

I'm not sure how what you have was interpreted, but I'm guessing since the `:unless` value evaluates to `false`, it was as if it wasn't there.

For the client-side jQuery rules, I don't think the `unless` option exists. The appropriate option is `depends`:

```js
$(function() { 
  $('[name="myform[address]"]').rules('add',
                 { "maxlength":50, 
                   "required": {
                   "depends": function(){
                       return $("input:radio[name=located_in_us]:checked").val() != "1"; // I think this should get the value of the radio button, but double check...
                     }
                   }, 
                   "messages": {"required":"Required field, please enter your address."}
                 });
});
```

Comment: I tried what you gave me, now the javascript looks like this:  `code`"unless":{}

Comment: @ews2001 The code I gave was for the server-side validation. I updated my answer with some client-side code that I think might help. Let me know.

Comment: Your javascript makes sense, but the <script></script> line shown in my question is automatically created by the object and added to the page source.  How can I manipulate the javascript created by the object or at least force it to use custom js and turn the default script creation off?

Comment: @ews2001 What are you using to produce your views?